# Show More or Show Less link if text is too much in Column in WebGrid MVC c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I am working on WebGrid of MVC with jquery,
Here in my grid, there is comment column which has more text in it which is creating a scroll.

I want to give a show more or show less link in this grid.

How Can I do it.

Here is my grid

[image]

Comment: Just keep a condition , if the length of comment greater than show the ShowMore . It the comment length selected mode keep the flag or length of the comment equal enable Show less. Keep this value in the hidden field while binding the data to your webgrid. Then play with this value. Instead of keep on call the requests to server

Comment: In jqGrid - we have an option - 
    { key: false, name: 'Message', index: 'Message', classes: "more" },

any such option in Mvc WebGrid ??

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a jquery function --

```
 $('.more').each(function () {
        var content = $(this).html();

        if (content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

            $(this).html(html);
        }

});
```

and to change Label text --

```
 $(".morelink").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
```

and finally, I added `.more` class in WebGrid.

```
grid.Column("outBoundMoveOrder.Comment", header: "Comment", style: "more"),
```

Happy Learning !!